# Check for condition in row, then print column value

Tags: excel, row, vlookup

I need to check through a number of column's in Excel. The Columns are filled with 1's & 0's. If a 1 is found then I need to print the value of the header column. There can be multiple 1's appearing in each row which is 5 columns wide.

```
+---+----+----+----+----+----+---------+
|   | A  | B  | C  | D  | E  | RESULTS |
+---+----+----+----+----+----+---------+
| 1 | R1 | R2 | R3 | R4 | R5 |         |
+---+----+----+----+----+----+---------+
| 2 | 1  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 1  | R1,R5   |
+---+----+----+----+----+----+---------+
| 3 | 0  | 1  | 0  | 0  | 0  | R2      |
+---+----+----+----+----+----+---------+
| 4 | 0  | 0  | 1  | 1  | 0  | R3,R4   |
+---+----+----+----+----+----+---------+
```

I have been trying various Vlookup functions however I can only get one result per a line. Not two or three.

The formatting of the output doesn't matter as much. As long at the output is unique to the value then it's fine.

Comment: Can you also upload a screenshot of how you're expecting your output to be?

Comment: Hello, The expected output is the displayed ASCII table. The results column can vary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can get this done using an Array formula. The formula you need to use is :  `=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(A2:E2=1,$A$1:$E$1,""))`

**Note**: Please note that this is an array formula. So after entering the formula you should be hitting "`CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`" **NOT "ENTER"**
[image: TextJoin]